Difference between C-score calculated by sksurv.metrics vs lifeline
I am currently trying to train a deep learning model with CoxPh loss, (kind of like deepSurv but different model. The thing is when I evaluate the model using C-statistics, the s-score from sksurv  is different than that from lifeline library.
I found a helpful comment here. but I am looking for more explanation. Can anyone help?
Thanks
from lifelines.utils import concordance_index
concordance_index(event_times=times, predicted_scores=pred, event_observed=events)

from sksurv.metrics import concordance_index_censored
concordance_index_censored(events == 1, times, pred)[0]

This is c-score by scikit-survival
This is c-score by lifelines
Note that I trained the model with same setting.
